# Value to return to denote invalid value

Tags: c#

Say you have a function that returns an enum:

```
public enum ServerStatus
{
    Down,
    Up
}

private ServerStatus GetServerStatus(int time)
{
    if (time >= 0 && time < 12)
    {
        return ServerStatus.Down;
    }
    else if (time >= 12 && time <= 23)
    {
        return ServerStatus.Up;
    }
    else
    {
        return ?? // Server status is neither Up nor Down
    } 
}
```

Should I:

1. Add "Neither" to ServerStatus
2. Makes GetServerStatus return ServerStatus? and return null
3. Return a another bool that indicate if the value is meaningful

Comment: As an aside, I'd probably rename "time" to "hour", "hourOfDay", or something

Comment: I agree. But this is a fake, toy example that I thought out just to illustrate my point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If that case should never happen in practice, and you don't expect to have to produce something other than 'Up' and 'Down', then you should throw an exception.

Comment: ArgumentOutOfRangeException, probably; +1

Comment: The condition should never happen: if an exception is thrown, I will still need to return a valid value, no?

Comment: No; there is no return value if you throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to throw an exception then you could always have an Unknown enum value. For example server status could be Up, Down or Unknown. The unknown status could be valid in some cases (e.g. if you cant get a connection to the server). This unknown value could be tested like a boolean value to decide if the answer is meaningful if appropriate.

I'm not saying that this is better than an ArgumentOutOfRangeException, just that it is another way of dealing with the problem. Your calling code could always throw the exception depending on other criteria.

Answer (score 2):

```
private ServerStatus GetSeverStatus(int time)
{
    if (time >= 0 && time < 12)
    {
        return ServerStatus.Down;
    }

    if (time >= 12 && time <= 23)
    {
        return ServerStatus.Up;
    }

    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of "how do I enforce my function preconditions".  You have several ways to do it.

One way that I really appreciate is: have a very simple 'programmed by contract' function that handles the pure business logic: assert a valid precondition.  Build a "safe" function on top of that, that assures the input *is* valid.

```
// with a 'validity' return type
public Pair<bool,ServerStatus> checkedGetServerStatus( uint time ) {
   Pair<bool,ServerStatus> p;
   p.first = false;
   if( time > 23 ) return p;

   p.first = true;
   p.second = GetServerStatus( (int)time );
   return p;
}

// or with an exception
public ServerStatus GetServerStatusEx( uint time ) {
   if( time > 23 ) throw InvalidArgumentException(time);

   return GetServerStatus( (int)time );
}
```

Another, maybe better, approach would be to change the supplied function argument type into something that cannot be wrong.

```
class ServerTime {
    public ServerTime( uint hours ) { seconds = (hours%24)*3600; }
    private uint seconds;
}

public ServerStatus GetServerStatus( ServerTime time ) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My thinking would be along these lines:

If it's an exceptional case (1 in 10,000 calls, once a year?) or an unrecoverable error then raise an exception.

If the "unknown" case isn't exceptional or it is a recoverable error I'd go with an "unknown" value. The question then becomes do you add a third value or go with an nullable type?

If it's quite likely then add a third state "unknown" or "unobtainable".

If it's not very likely then go with the nullable type.

Which ever solution you use you might need some way of finding out exactly why you couldn't determine the server status - there might be no connection, the user credentials might be invalid, there might be too many connections etc. - to determine whether to retry immediately, retry after some delay or simply abort.